# Fast algorithm of multiple numbers sequential decrements until limit of sum

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, iteration

I have:

- an ordered list of `dc` objects that have a float field `result` in it.
- `limit` value for sum of `result`.
- `pack` (not a better name ever) is a value of decreasing.

Problem:

- I need to sequentially decrease `results` for each `dc` until sum of all `results` will be less or equal `limit` (without assigning `result` values below 0).

After some profiling I got this code:

```python
while(self.sum > self.limit):
    for dc in self.dc:
        if dc.result > 0:
            # max() too slow here
            result = (
                dc.result - self.pack
                if dc.result - self.pack > 0
                else 0
                )
            # Prevent sum() count for all list on each iteration
            self.sum -= dc.result - result
            dc.result = result

            if self.sum <= self.limit:
                break
```

But it has a low performance for small `self.pack` values (the code is doing too many iterations).

Is there a way to make this method faster?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not too concerned how much you remove from the pack as long as it ensures it is less than sum, then you could just implement DC as a max heap (priority queue), and pop it every time until sum is <= self.limit. That would significantly speed up processing time especially in big data sets.

Edit:
Since dc is an ordered list, just treat it like a stack and pop from the back and remove from the pack (since the "heaviest" things are at the back).